# Android APK - Google form to APK with camera access

Tags: android, apk, google-forms

I'm trying to convert a google form into a APK with android studio, which I was able to do with online tutorials. The issue that I have now is, when I click the add file on the form it does allow me to use the default camera app. I thought that adding permission will help, but it did not.

What code must I add or what other APK builder apps are there that will allow me to add the default camera app when I select add file or upload on my form.

Comment: Can you please add more code details about how your form looks (to add the file)? As well your permissions code?

Comment: Here is a link to similar form that I will use. 
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLScRC10DzGXZ9Uvlc0qnf2Djv2qT3PF1AmuM0Q9e4fDJXzeA6g/viewform

I'm using WebView to call the form, but when I click select file from device on the form it only give me the device storage but if I use the form with chrome the camera app pops up as a option.

Permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>

Comment: I dont think it will be possible to get the camera.

Because you are using WebView the app just iframes the website (which has a google form) into your app and in that website google forms ask for a file hence it goes to the device storage.

Rebuild the form in android native and then you can use the Android camera API - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera